# R Shiny error handling on separate server files

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have an R Shiny app where the server.R file is split into several separate server files; one for each tab.

I am struggling with finding a method to ensure that if an error occurs in one server file, then the entire Shiny app does not crash, but instead a message is displayed telling the user that tab x contains an error and can therefore not be used.

I have experimented with using Shiny's validate function as well as using tryCatch in combination with functions etc., which to some extend does help with error handling, but not the the extend that I am looking for here.

Below you can find a code snippet of the test-app that I have made so as to illustrate the issue I am trying to solve.

server.R :

```
library(shiny);
library(shinydashboard);

server <- function(session, input, output) {

  source(file.path("server", "server_tab_1.R"), local = TRUE)$value

  source(file.path("server", "server_tab_2.R"), local = TRUE)$value

} # end of server
```

ui.R :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Test", disable = FALSE),

  dashboardSidebar(

    sidebarMenu(id = "menu_tabs",
                menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab_1"),
                menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab_2")
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    tabItems(  

      tabItem(tabName = "tab_1",

              source(file.path("ui", "ui_tab_1.R"),  local = TRUE)$value

      ), 

      tabItem(tabName = "tab_2",

              source(file.path("ui", "ui_tab_2.R"),  local = TRUE)$value

      )

    ) # end of tabItems
  ) # end of dahsboardBody
) # end of dashboardPage
```

sever_tab_1.R

```
observe({

  output$textOutputTab1 <- renderText({ 
    "No error on tab 1"
  })

})
```

server_tab_2.R

```
observe({

  output$textOutputTab2 <- renderText({ 
    "Error on tab 2"
  })

  stop("Forcing error in server_tab_2")

})
```

ui_tab_1.R

```
tabPanel("Tab 1",
         fluidRow(
           column(width = 12, offset = 0,
                  textOutput("textOutputTab1")
           ) # end of column
         ) # end of fluidRow
)
```

ui_tab_2.R

```
tabPanel("Tab 2",
         fluidRow(
           column(width = 12, offset = 0,
                  textOutput("textOutputTab2")
           ) # end of column
         ) # end of fluidRow
)
```

Comment: You can use `info` function from `shinyjs` package to display the message.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed true. However, the main issue I have is finding some logic or method to ensure that the entire app does not crash when an error occurs in either one of the server files.